# DataGrid CellEditEnding event raised after binding sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid bound to a collection of items. In the code behind I have subscribed to the CellEditEnding event:

```
dg.CellEditEnding += dg_CellEditEnding;
```

I hoped this event would be raised before the changed value was updated in the bound object. But it appears that sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't. If I change a value in the grid and press enter, the event is raised first, followed by the bound object being updated. If I press tab, or click on another cell in the same row, they happen in reverse.

Why does this happen? I need a way to see a changed value before it is applied to the bound object. Is there another event I can subscribe to instead? I realize this is not the traditional MVVM approach. This is part of a custom datagrid control with some requirements that are hard to implement in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the same  body for the CellEditEnding event for a "LostFocus" event. This way, whatever you want to happen when its done editing also happens when you leave the cell.

At least, that's how I expect it to work. Try it out and let me know!

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to all the events for datagridcells, if you dont think LostFocus will work for what you're looking for.